# How to incorporate the multiple url into a get fuction python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the Below Python function which gets the alert querying a url and this is working.

However i have to place more queries to the `url` section which i am not able to figure out.

### Below is working Function:

```
BASE_URL = "https://synergy.hpe.example.com/rest/"

def get_alerts(session, session_id):
    try:
        return session.get(
            url=f"{BASE_URL}/resource-alerts"
            headers={
                "accept": "application/json",
                "content-type": "text/csv",
                "x-api-version": "2",
                "auth": session_id,
            },
            verify=False,
            stream=True
        )
```

I need to loop through multiple alert queries along with BASE_URL:

```
 "/resource-alerts?count=500&start=501"
 "/resource-alerts?count=500&start=1001"
 "/resource-alerts?count=500&start=15001",
```

### What i have tried with a for-loop:

While doing a for-loop, it works but looks like over writing the return function hence returning the output of only single get alert query.

```
qr = [ 'resource-alerts', 'resource-alerts?count=500&start=501', 'resource-alerts?count=500&start=1001', 'resource-alerts?count=500&start=1501' ]

def get_resource_alerts_response(session, session_id):
    try:
        for res in qr:
            return session.get(
                url=f"{BASE_URL}{res}",
                #url=f"{BASE_URL}/resource-alerts?count=-1",
                headers={
                    "accept": "application/json",
                    "content-type": "text/csv",
                    "x-api-version": "2",
                    "auth": session_id,
                },
                verify=False,
                stream=True
                )
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as req_exception:
        raise ResourceAlertsRetrievalFailure(
            f"Could not fetch resource alerts: {req_exception}"
        )
```

Comment: Have you tried writing a `for` loop which repeats the original code for every URL?

Comment: `session.get` only handles one URL at a time, just like how your web browser's URL bar only handles one URL at a time. How do you *normally* write code to do a similar thing multiple times? What happened when you tried applying that technique here?

Comment: Then Stack Overflow is not the right site to get help; please try to actually learn Python from a tutorial.

Comment: Hi @kulfi, understandable, but the help you can get here is "use a for-loop to call this function once for each URL." Please learn about for-loops from a python tutorial, and if you get stuck come back for help about the specific problem from using this language feature. Good luck and happy learning!

Comment: @mkrieger1, i have tried to get a for loop bu that looks like over writing the `return` hence not getting all results.

Comment: @alexis, thanks for the comment , i Just edited the post with the `for-loop` trial.

Comment: (put the function call inside the for-loop, not the loop inside the function ;-) )

Answer (score 1):

With a bit of faking because the code you submitted does not allow me to reproduce the issue :

```py
ResourceAlertsRetrievalFailure = Exception
class FakeGetRequest:
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("GET ", tuple(args), dict(kwargs))
session_id = "..."
session = FakeGetRequest()
```

I can get your code to work :

```py
import requests

BASE_URL = "https://synergy.hpe.example.com/rest/"
qr = ['resource-alerts',
      'resource-alerts?count=500&start=501',
      'resource-alerts?count=500&start=1001',
      'resource-alerts?count=500&start=1501']


def get_resource_alerts_response(session, session_id):
    try:
        return session.get(
            url=f"{BASE_URL}{res}",
            headers={
                "accept": "application/json",
                "content-type": "text/csv",
                "x-api-version": "2",
                "auth": session_id,
            },
            verify=False,
            stream=True
            )
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as req_exception:
        raise ResourceAlertsRetrievalFailure(
            f"Could not fetch resource alerts: {req_exception}"
        )

for res in qr:
    get_resource_alerts_response(session, session_id)
```

Comment: @ Lenormju, thanks a lot and  +1 for the code, but the value of the loop is getting over-written

Comment: @kulfi that's what `for` loops do : they change the value of the loop variable (here `res`) for you. What you may want to do is to assign the result of `get_resource_alerts_response` to a variable and something with it **inside the loop** (or it will get over-written), or `append` it to a list, to be processed adter the loop ended. I recommend you follow some tutorials on Python loops, it would help you understand how it works.